# State the value of x after the statement

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

State the value of x after the statement if P(x) then x := 1 is executed, where P(x) is the statement “x > 1,” if the value of x when this statement is reached is

1. x = 0.
2. x = 1.
3. x = 2.

this answer :

1. F , x=0
2. F, x=1
3. T, x=1

I don't understand the question  and answer , can you explain it ?

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you what to say. Which statements? Can you explain your question so we can answer it?

Comment: State the value of x after the statement if P(x) then x := 1 is executed, where P(x) is the statement “x > 1,” if the value of x when this statement is reached is

x = 0.

x = 1.

x = 2.

Comment: This is a bit confusing. First, $P(x)$ is a predicate (not statement). Now, considering the values of $P(0), P(1), P(2)$, what *precisely* do you want to ask?

Comment: thank you and sorry I don't understand what you're meaning!

Comment: again, thank you I got the answer \/

Comment: Don't worry, the important is you got the answer you needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that we are working with a pseudo-programmming language and that we are asked to evaluate what happens with the "conditional instruction" :

> "if $x > 1$, then set $x := 1$".

When :

- $x=0$, we have that $0 > 1$ is false; thus the operation of assigning $1$ to $x$ is not performed and $x$ has the value $0$
- $x=1$, we have that $1 > 1$ is false; thus the operation of assigning $1$ to $x$ is not performed and $x$ has the value $1$
- $x=2$, we have that $2 > 1$ is true; now the operation of assigning $1$ to $x$ is performed and $x$ change its value to $1$.